# HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() vs HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName()

Tags: java, security, http, jakarta-ee, active-directory

These two seem to be doing the same things. Can anyone explain the main difference between the two?  When would you use one vs the other?

[HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29)

[HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html#getName())

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A `Principal` represents someone who could potentially authenticate with your application. The Principal's *name* depends on the authentication method used:

- a username such as "fred" (in the case of HTTP Basic authentication)
- a Distinguished Name such as "CN=bob,O=myorg" (in the case of X.509 client certificates - in which case a [X500Principal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html) may be returned)

`getRemoteUser()` returns "the login of the user" which, in the case of HTTP Basic authentication, will also be the username; it doesn't map cleanly in the X.509 client certificate case though, since the user doesn't enter a "login" as such - in the example above, we could use the Distinguished Name or simply the CN, "bob".

The Javadocs state that "whether the user name is sent with each subsequent request depends on the browser and type of authentication", suggesting that `getRemoteUser()` was originally meant to provide data *only for requests in which a username was entered*. This, however, would result in it returning `null` for the majority of requests when cookie-based auth is in use - not too helpful!

In reality, `getRemoteUser()` often just calls `getUserPrincipal().getName()`; verified in Tomcat 6 and Jetty 6/7.

Comment: For SPNEGO authentication against an Active Directory domain, the Principal's name is sAMAccountName@NTDOMAIN while getRemoteUser() returns just sSAMAccountName.

Answer (score 3):

The `getUserPrincipal()` method returns an object of some class derived from the `Principal` interface, which is an **abstraction** of the entity that is the "user" responsible for the request. From it you get an actual object that, depending on the implementing class, you can use to get all sorts of information about that user/identity. One of those properties is the string-representation of the name of the user/identity, which you obtain by calling `getName()`.

`getRemoteUser()` is really just a shortcut to getting that string-representation. You don't have access to any other methods implemented by the implementing class, not do you have access to the object itself, just the string-representation of the name.

For most use-cases that I am familiar with, that string-representation is what you want; I *believe* this is why `getRemoteUser()` exists - it's a common case so there's an easy/quick way to get access to it without actually getting a reference to an implementing class object.

Comment: I am looking for more insight.  What is the semantics of both… how are they different.  Will they every give you two different results? Are they always the same?

Comment: +1 this seems pretty clear to me. I mean you can always look at the code, but I imagine one is derived from the other.

Comment: -1. **getRemoteUser()** can be **null** when  **getUserPrincipal()** is not... I get this issue with *Spring MVC test framework*. The **getUserPrincipal().getName()** is the right thing to use!

Comment: >`One of those properties is the string-representation of the name of the user/identity, which you obtain by calling getName().` - I'm not 100% sure this is right. What you explain sounds more like the JAAS `Subject` type, which is not exposed by Java EE. The Subject is a bag of principles, with each principal somewhat like an attribute. The `userPrincipal` is really only the username. `getName` doesn't refer to user.name, but to the name of the Principal, actually more like the value of the Principal. It's an overly general interface though than can be rather confusing.

Comment: An example is the SpnegoPrincipal class returned when you're using SPNEGO for single sign-on authentication to Active Directory or another Kerberos source. The setup I'm working with returns sAMAccountName for getRemoteUser and sAMAccountName@NTDOMAIN for getUserPrincipal().getName(). If I cast to a SpnegoPrincipal, I can call .getRealm() and get the NT DOMAIN. In this case getRemoteUser isn't quite a shortcut to getUserPrincipal().getName().

Answer (score 1):

A bit related issue:

People converting older IBM Portlet API code to JSR168 one had to change PortletRequest to HttpServletRequest in some method parameters, but then from WPS6.1 and up they can't cast that to PortletRequest (it doesn't implement the respective interface anymore as it seems) and if they call "getRemoteUser" directly on the HttpServletRequest they get back null (some say a workarround is to enable application security option in WAS [WebSphere Application Server], others say more security-related markup is needed in web.xml)

A workarround seems to be to use PUMA, but of course that is IBM WebSphere specific. Probably at other Portlet Containers there are other vendor-specific workarrounds if one finds that getRemoteUser always returns null (judging from other replies then getUserPrincipal().getName() also returns null if getRemoteUser is implemented as just a shortcut to that one).

BTW, the PUMA code I mention above is here, since it's a bit hard to find what works in WPS6.1+:

```
import com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.PortletServiceHome;
import com.ibm.portal.um.*;
import com.ibm.portal.um.exceptions.PumaException;
import com.ibm.portal.puma.User;

//...

public String getCurrentUser(){
  try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    Name myjndiname = new CompositeName(PumaHome.JNDI_NAME);
    PumaHome myHome = (PumaHome) ctx.lookup(myjndiname); 
    if (myHome!=null) {
      PumaProfile pumaProfile = myHome.getProfile();
      com.ibm.portal.um.User user = (com.ibm.portal.um.User)pumaProfile.getCurrentUser();
      List attributes = new ArrayList();
      attributes.add("uid");
      Map userAttributes = pumaProfile.getAttributes(user,attributes);
      return (String) userAttributes.get("uid");
    }
  }
```