# Active directory auth Tomcat - Read username in Action?

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, active-directory

I have implemented Active Directory authentication for my Struts 2 web application in Tomcat. I want to be able to use the username of the logged in user within the application. How can I read it within an action?

Comment: I got it working with Servlet Context getRemoteUser()... What is the difference between this and getUserPrincipal?

Comment: Don't worry I found out here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680843/httpservletrequest-getremoteuser-vs-httpservletrequest-getuserprincipal-getn

Comment: Doing that makes it more difficult to test. Why would you not use the abstractions provided by the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Struts2 there is `org.apache.struts2.interceptor.PrincipalAware` interface which sets `org.apache.struts2.interceptor.PrincipalProxy` into your action. Implement it in your action and use this object to get user principal.

Using `PrincipalAware` interface is preferable way to get user principal. From javadoc:

> This interface is only relevant if the Action is used in a servlet environment.
>     By using this interface you will not become tied to servlet environment.

Comment: What does it mean by "not become tied to servlet environment"?

Comment: @user1277546 Precisely that; once you get servlet spec artifacts in your code it may become more difficult to test. Abstracting away from dependencies can make testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

Does it not integrate with the Servlet Context? You should be able to get it with:

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest().getUserPrincipal().getName();
```